# Problem retrieving video from GoPro

Tags: usb, mount, video

I have a problem with retrieving videos from my GoPro. I am able to mount the GoPro and I see the "Get_started_with_GoPro.URL" file, but no video or image files. Similarly, I have that

```
$ gphoto2 -L
There is no file in folder '/'.                                                
There is 1 file in folder '/store_00010001'.
#1     Get_started_with_GoPro.URL r-     1 KB text/html
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM'.
There is no file in folder '/store_00010001/DCIM_00000001'.
```

Below is plenty of debugging output that might be helpful in drilling down on the problem.

As far as gvfs-mount is concerned, I have

```
$ gvfs-mount -li
Volume(0): GoPro HERO
Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGPhoto2)
ids:
unix-device: '/dev/bus/usb/001/006'
activation_root=gphoto2://[usb:001,006]/
themed icons:  [camera-photo]
symbolic themed icons:  [camera-photo-symbolic]  [camera-symbolic]  [camera-photo]  [camera]
can_mount=1
can_eject=0
should_automount=1
```

Running dmesg after plugin in the device gives me

```
[ 1191.640449] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1195.017487] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1195.203112] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2672, idProduct=000c
[ 1195.203117] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1195.203119] usb 1-1: Product: GoPro HERO
[ 1195.203121] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: GoPro
[ 1195.203122] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: C3111025740636
```

and lsusb -v on device

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2672:000c                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2672
  idProduct          0x000c
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 GoPro
  iProduct                2 GoPro HERO
  iSerial                 3 C3111025740636
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                4mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass         6 Imaging
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Still Image Capture
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Picture Transfer Protocol (PIMA 15470)
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval              16
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Struggling with the same issue.  I thought it might be related to exfat (which I think is what gopro used on the sdcard) but installing that from the repos made no difference.

Comment: I've been messing around some. I found that version of libgphoto2 2.14 in an old ubuntu release works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a bit hacky, but works:

1. Install virtualbox / vagrant
2. Follow the instructions on http://code-chronicle.blogspot.de/2014/08/connect-usb-device-through-vagrant.html to enable usb in virtualbox.
3. Setup the vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]
     vb.customize ["usbfilter", "add", "0",
                   "--target", :id,
                   "--name", "gopro",
                   "--manufacturer", "GoPro",
                   "--product", "GoPro Hero"]

  config.vm.provision "shell", :inline => "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install gphoto2"
  end

end
```

4. do vagrant up, vagrant ssh
5. sudo gphoto2 -L lists your videos and pictures
6. sudo gphoto2 -P downloads all your files

Comment: Oddly enough 'gphoto2 -P' only works once after starting the VM.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same problem under UbuntuGnome Xenial and a GoPro Session Hero 4.

Problem comes from a bug in libgphoto2. This library needs to be updated to version 2.5.10 to solve the problem and to get back a full access to your GoPro.

I've explained the needed steps in this article http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/347-ubuntu-xenial-gopro-usb-access-bug

Cheers.

Comment: The link is dead :/

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial):

1. [download the following updates from the next ubuntu verison "The Yakkety Yak"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2/+index)

   - [libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb)
   - [libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb)
2. install them

   `sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_i386.deb libgphoto2-6_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb`

You can now import videos with Shotwell.

Comment: I also had to do `sudo apt-get install libexif12 libusb-1.0-0 libgd3 libgphoto2-port12` then `sudo apt-get -f install` to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Note that with the SDCard inserted in a SDCard reader I can see all files, so I think it is not due to the filesystem.

I have reported the issue to GoPro support. **They say that GoPro doesn't give support for Linux**, that could lead to think that GoPro do not work with Linux.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could improve your answer by adding a link to any official resource where they state this, instead of just telling it without citation.

Comment: GoPro not supporting linux shouldn't stop the linux community from supporting GoPros. Somebody just needs to figure out what the issue is ...

Comment: Just a note to confirm I was also able to access my files by reading the sdcard directly using an adapter. Be nice to just plug the camera in and read it directly, but being able to at least read the sdcard is a reasonable compromise for me.

Comment: I have a mail from GoPro official support stating that: "nous ne fournissons aucun support technique pour votre système d´exploitation LINUX" (in english: "we don't provide any tech support for your Linux OS").

But they gave me a workaround: they proposed me to send a external SD Card reader for free, that will solve the issue because the SD Card reader will behave as a standard mass storage.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my new GoPro Hero, could not see pictures or video from the sd card, I tried everything.  Used a different computer (both with Ubuntu 16.04) and everything worked great.  The only difference was the one that worked did NOT have VLC installed.  Pulled up the photos with Imageviewer, and the video with Videos (Totem).  Went back to the first computer and removed VLC, now everything works great, just like the other computer using Imageviewer and Videos.
Hope this helps someone.
PS now also my little Vivitar Lifecam works also with 16.04