# Copying files from GoPro 6 to Ubuntu 16 via USB

Tags: usb

I just bought my first GoPro (Hero 6), and I was expecting it to function as a standard USB device, like almost all digital cameras and phones do nowadays when connected to a PC. Unfortunately [it seems](https://askubuntu.com/a/757372/430574) that this is not the case, and instead it requires specific software which isn't available on Linux.

Are there any 3rd party solutions at the moment, or must I just directly copy files from the SD card forever?

I have installed gphoto2 2.5.9 but `gphoto2 -L` prints

```
*** Error ***              
Could not detect any camera
*** Error (-105: 'Unknown model') ***
```

Any suggestions on how to get the USB working for my GoPro Hero 6?

Update:

```
$ gphoto2 --version
gphoto2 2.5.15

Copyright (c) 2000-2017 Lutz Mueller and others

gphoto2 comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. You may
redistribute copies of gphoto2 under the terms of the GNU General Public
License. For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING.

This version of gphoto2 is using the following software versions and options:
gphoto2         2.5.15         gcc, popt(m), exif, cdk, aa, jpeg, readline
libgphoto2      2.5.16         all camlibs, gcc, ltdl, EXIF
libgphoto2_port 0.12.0         iolibs: disk ptpip serial usb1 usbdiskdirect usbscsi, gcc, ltdl, USB, serial without locking
```

And

```
$ gphoto2 --list-cameras | grep -i gopro
    "GoPro HERO"
    "GoPro HERO +"
    "GoPro HERO 3+"
    "GoPro HERO 4"
    "GoPro HERO4 Silver"
    "GoPro HERO5 Black"
    "GoPro HERO5 Session"
```

GoPro 6 doesn't seem to be listed therere.

Comment: Now, until Gopro Hero8 black is supported (12/2022)

Comment: Could you elaborate, gphoto supports gopros 1 - 8?

Comment: "GoPro HERO"
 "GoPro HERO +"
 "GoPro HERO 3+"
 "GoPro HERO 4"
 "GoPro HERO4 Silver"
 "GoPro HERO5 Black"
 "GoPro HERO5 Session"
 "GoPro HERO6 Black"
 "GoPro HERO7 Black"
 "GoPro HERO7 Silver"
 "GoPro HERO7 White"
 "GoPro HERO8 Black"